# Limit of an integral with changing domain

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to figure out the limit :

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}} \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^{\!n}dx$$

Now the problem is that as $n$ rises so does the range of integration, otherwise I could use Dini's theorem to show uniform convergence to $\int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$, but from what I gather the idea of taking the limit of a sequence of integrals into the integral only works if the domain remains static. My intuition however tells me that I would get $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ as a result, since obviously the expression above would behave almost exactly like  $\int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2}dx$ for large enough $n$'s - my problem is hereby with the formality.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Look at this integral as the following

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^{\infty}\chi_{[0,\sqrt{n}]}(x)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^ndx,$$

where $\chi_{[0,\sqrt{n}]}(x)$ is the function that is $1$ on the interval $[0,\sqrt{n}]$ and $0$ otherwise. Then apply a dominated convergence argument.

Comment: Ok, so uniform convergence isn't the way to go as obviously there's equality there, but obviously there's no uniform convergence. However, I still don't think I can look at the limit inside the integral. By the way i'm dealing with a Riemann integral and not lebesgue (Read about the dominated convergence argument on wikipedia and it doesn't seem to hold for Riemann integrals)

Comment: Try monotone convergence theorem here. It's very useful and holds in the Riemann case.